# Wine problem when playing Ace of Spades

Tags: wine

So I've been trying to play Ace of Spades for a while now. And yesterday I was able to do that for about 5 seconds before realizing that the mouse wasn't nearly sensitive enough. So I changed the sensitivity in nano and tried to run it again I got this error when I typed in `wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Ace\ of\ Spades/client.exe aos://3735504972`

```
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:msvcr90:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x3a04c4) stub
fixme:msvcr90:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x35f78c) stub
fixme:msvcr90:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1911884) stub
```

I tried uninstalling Ace of Spades and reinstalled it still there. I also tried doing that with wine, even deleting the `~/.wine` directory or whatever

It's important to note that I've had Linux for about 3 days so I know the very basics but beyond that I can't really do much

I think it's wine because when I googled it only wine errors came up but hey I'm probably wrong.

Feel free to tell me to do something I've already done, just explain it to me a bit simpler than usual

Answer (score 2):

Simply enter the following three commands in a terminal pressing enter after each one (don't include the $ symbol, and replace USERNAME with your username).

```
$ gconftool-2 --set --type=string /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/aos/command 'wine "/home/USERNAME/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Ace of Spades/client.exe" -"%s"'

$ gconftool-2 --set --type=boolean /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/aos/enabled true

$ gconftool-2 --set --type=boolean /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/aos/needs_terminal false
```

Then you can launch the game like normal by going to www.ace-spades.com  or http://iammorthor.com/aos/ (I like this one better) and clicking on the name of the server you would like to join.

**Links**

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=12965